# How to get all user details from laravel5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

How i get all users in laravel 5.3 . i am using barryvdh for cors

this is my RegisterController which is in Auth folder

```
public function index(){
      return Users::all();
  }
```

above code gives all the user data if in route below we do not use middleware
and if we use middleware then i got error unauthenticated . so i want to get all user data using middleware in route . How can i get

```
 Route::get('/users','Auth\RegisterController@index')->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: use return syntax

Comment: U can use    return Your_model _name:: get()

Comment: code looks fine . what is the problem with the code

Comment: Your controller should pass data to a view, say 'users.blade', and return that view, so that you can use all users in the view.

Comment: @JohnDoe i m working in api so i dont use view and above entire code gives me single user details but i want all user details . Thank You

Comment: Do you need to do this this way due to any reasons. because I would suggest to do this differently? But if you say that this returns you a user, I would guess that you may only have one user in your database. Can you check in your database if there are more than one user?

Comment: your code works if i m using middleware in route

Comment: I updated my answer, can you try my new suggestion and tell me if it works

Comment: The `auth` middleware will block any unauthenticated users from accessing the endpoint, so it's behaving correctly in your example. If you want to access the endpoint without even logging in, then don't use `auth` middleware for that endpoint. What's your issue exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this :

```
public function index(){
 $users = Users::get();
 return $users;
}
```

Hope this work for you!

Comment: Route::get('/users','Auth\RegisterController@index')->middleware('auth');  this route gives only single user details how i can get all user details using middleware in api.

Comment: Make sure that your model name is 'Users' not 'User'.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to get all data of your user table you simple have to do following:

```
# Middleware group if user is logged in
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function ()
{
    Route::get('home', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function ()
    {
        Route::get('get', ['as' => 'getUser', 'uses' => 'UserController@getUser']);
    });
});
```

And in your controller you can do something like this:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function getUser(Request $request)
    {
        $users = DB::table('users')->get();
        return $users;
    }
}
```

If you want add something to that return you probably have to create a relation between your models, and call them in your method and return them.

If you still have any questions or if I understood something wrong feel free to comment on this answer.

**Edit:**

If you want to return all user with an api route you can do following in your api routes:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

Comment: i want to use in api routes so there is no login process . i m using barryvdh cors for cors handle and in laraval i m using passport. using passport token how can i fetch all user

Comment: Can you please explain your question with MORE informations, it is not helpful if you just post snippets here and there. So please update your question with more information and code, tell me if you did so, I am going to have a look at it after you did that.

Comment: How i get all users in laravel 5.3 . i am using barryvdh for cors 

this is my RegisterController which is in Auth folder

    public function index(){
          return Users::all();
      }

above code gives all the user data if in route below we do not use middleware
and if we use middleware then i got error unauthenticated . so i want to get all user data using middleware in route . How can i get all user 

     Route::get('/users','Auth\RegisterController@index')->middleware('auth');

Comment: Add that to your question above and format the code please, this is not readable at all

Comment: Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Routing\Router::middleware(), called in /home/thebrainout/public_html/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 237 and defined
i got this error

Comment: @MaheshBhattarai what excatly did you do

Comment: Sorry I think you lack of knowledge, please have a look at the documentations again [routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing) , [api / oauth ](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function index()
 {

$userDetail = Users::get();
dd($userDetails);

 }
```

Comment: i m using passport token but i get only one user from this token . how i get all users read and write from this token . but this token gives me error unauthenticated while getting all users